# Probabilistic version of picking objects around a circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let n objects places around a circle numbered from 1 to n. We start from 1 and pick the k$^{th}$ object with probability $p$. Hence at first round objects at positions 1, 1 + k , 1 + 2k , ... and so on are picked with probability $p$. This goes on around the circle skipping the positions that already been picked. What is the probability that i$^{th}$ is going to be picked as the number of picking attempts goes to $\infty$.

Comment: You might want to look into the [problem of Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Comment: This problem actually takes inspiration from that.